# Unable to search for a key inside a python dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the below dict in place-

```
import collections
tags = [
    {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "Peter"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Email",
        "Value": "Peter@xyz.com"

    },
    {
        "Key": "City",
        "Value": "Paris"

    },
]
```

Im trying to look out for the value of `Email` address, but im unable to.

Kindly suggest a logic for me to find this value out-

Comment: Have you tried `tags.get("Email")` ?

Comment: @quantik have you tried that yourself?

Comment: @quantik: No, this is not working..

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? I dont find anything wrong with the question.

Answer (score 4):

Iterate over the `tags`, check each `tag`'s `'Key'` for `'Email'`.  When found, get the `'Value'`.

```
for tag in tags:
    if tag['Key'] == 'Email':
        print('Email is', tag['Value'])
        break
```

Comment: this is working perfectly even without the "break" section.. Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[dic['Value'] for dic in tags if dic['Key'] =="Email"]
```

Output:

```
['Peter@xyz.com']
```

Update for multiple values:

Suppose you have:

```
tags = [
    {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "Peter"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Email",
        "Value": "Peter@xyz.com"

    },
    {
        "Key": "Email",
        "Value": "test@xyz.com"

    },

    {
        "Key": "City",
        "Value": "Paris"

    },
]
```

the output will be:

```
['Peter@xyz.com', 'test@xyz.com']
```

Comment: Tiny, Yes this is also working great `print([dic['Value'] for dic in tags if dic['Key'] == "Email"])`

Comment: @AlanJebakumar Yep, and it will find all values into a list for `Key =="Email"`